# How to change the status bar icon based on extra value from Urban Airship Pushnotification in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am developing an app with Urban Airship PushNotification. It is working for me, I am able to get the push notification also. My requirement is with Pushnotification I am passing an Extra Value, I want to change the status bar icon for the notification based on the Extra Value.Assume If the Extra Value is '1' I want to show my App Icon, if it is '2' I want to show another icon. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest disabling Urban Airship's notifications and handling the Push events manually.

To disable Urban Airship's notifications, override `BasicPushNotificationBuilder`:

```
BasicPushNotificationBuilder nb = new BasicPushNotificationBuilder() {
    @Override
    public Notification buildNotification(String alert,
            Map<String, String> extras) {
        return null;
    }
};
// Disable notifications
PushManager.shared().setNotificationBuilder(nb);
```

Then implement an intent receiver [according to the documentation here](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Client%3A+Android%3A+Push#ClientAndroidPush-CustomHandlingofPushEvents), and create your own `Notification` to meet your spec.